# Unable to start sqoop: jobtracker not found

Tags: hadoop, cassandra, sqoop

I'm getting an error like the title when I'm transfering data from mysql to cassandra with sqoop.

```
dse sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://<IP address>/Turkgen --username root --table mgs --cassandra-keyspace turkgen_ks --cassandra-table mgs --cassandra-thrift-host localhost --cassandra-create-schema
```

I run this command and I got the error:
**Unable to start sqoop: jobtracker not found**

**Edit:**

when i look the log files for jobtracker. There is an error like this :

**Does not contain a valid host:port authority: local**

How can I fix it ?

Comment: What version of DSE are you running this on. If you don't have a jobtracker then probably aren't running this on an analytics node.

Comment: dse version is 4.8.6. I installed Hadoop externally, i don't use hadoop that inside the dse. I am trying to realize data migration from mysql to cassandra following official manual of datastax but i got error that "unable to start sqoop:jobtracker not found". When i run the command "dse hive", i got same error.

Answer (score 0):

Type in shell jps and check whether job tracker is running.

If not then 
start-all.sh

Comment: start-all.sh command starts all hadoop services, but my hadoop services already run. However I tried your advice but i got same error. My problem is still continue.

Comment: try bin/hadoop dfsadmin -safemode leave

Answer (score 0):

Iam also a begineer but foll sol worked for me

please  see if /tmp in hdfs and make mapred its owner with 1777 permission
during set up there is possibility that /tmp in HDFS got deleted try and see

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that **HADOOP_CONF_DIR** or **YARN_CONF_DIR** points to the directory which contains the (client side) configuration files for the Hadoop cluster. If you use CDH, you need to make sure that the YARN gateway role is deployed on the node that you run your sqoop command.